# How to check the unitarity of the theory by having field equation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, unitarity, s-matrix-theory

Let's have some field equation of some field corresponding to particles with mass $m$ and spin $s$. How to check the [unitarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarity_%28physics%29) of the theory? May I do it without getting $S$-matrix? May the scalar product in a field space help?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65793/2451